# How can this switch statement be simplified?

Tags: c++

I have two switch statement on inside another.
Like this

```
switch(something)
{
case h:
     switch(s)
     {
     case e:
     break;
     default:
     }
break;
default:
}
```

Can i simplify it any way? Is there a way to use only one switch statement?
I thought of moving it to a different function but I'll need to pass a lot of variables.

Comment: If it bothers you and it can be done easily, move the inner switch to a function.

Comment: I agree with Jon.  pushing the inner switch into a function makes the code easier to read, and helps with maintainability.  As far as performance goes, there's nothing wrong with what you've got.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what 'something' and 's' are.

Also, based on this switch statement. You could remove it completely and get the same results.

Comment: +1 for the "based on this switch statement, you could remove it completely and get the same results". Smart arse!

Comment: @Ramilol Your switch statement currently does absolutely no work. It's empty.

Comment: As long as everyone is being pedantic, the evaluation of either 'something' or 's' could have side-effects, since they could be objects with implicit integral conversions.  C++ loves itself some side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a `break` after the default, since there shouldn't be any skippable statements after it.

```
switch(something)
{
case h:
     switch(s)
     {
     case e:
     break;
     default:
     }
break;
default:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try indenting it more to make it more readable, but I don't see how you could do it with one switch

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish with this logic we will not be able to siginificantly simplify this bit of code.

If the switch statements really are just checking for a single condition and then have default logic, this would probably be a little cleaner with if statements:

```
if (something == h)
{
     if (s == e)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        //default
    }
}
else
{
    //default
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?:

```
if((something == h) && (s == e))
{
    // Do something
}
```